# Retrieving an image source when another image is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve the source of an image depending on which separate image the user previously clicked on.

```
<div class="card1">
    <div>
    <a href="#" class="quickFlipCta"><img class="back" src="Memory Pals/Test Pictures/QuestionMark.gif" /></a>
    </div>

    <div>
    <a href="#" class="quickFlipCta"><img class="front" src="Memory Pals/Test Pictures/flower.gif" /></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card2">
    <div>
    <a href="#" class="quickFlipCta"><img class="back" src="Memory Pals/Test Pictures/QuestionMark.gif" /></a>
    </div>

    <div>
    <a href="#" class="quickFlipCta"><img class="front" src="Memory Pals/Test Pictures/flower.gif" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my specific example, I am trying to retrieve the source of "front" when "back" is clicked. Also, it must retrieve the source of "front" in the same card.

This is what I've tried, but I can't get it to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var found = 0;
        var last = null;

        $('img').each(function(index){
          $(this).attr('id','img-' + index);
        });    

        $('img').click(function(){
          if( last ) {
            if( ($(this).attr('src') == last.attr('src')) ) {
              $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
              last.css('visibility', 'hidden');
              found++;
            }
            if (found == 3) {
            window.location.href = "#play2"; 
            location.reload(); //resets found to 0
            }
            last = null;
          } else {
            last = $(this);
          }
        });
```

I realize it is not retrieving the source of "front," just the source of an image that the user has clicked on. How can I change it so it retrieves the source of "front" when "back" is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that may point you in the right direction:

```
$('img.back').click(function () {
    var frontSrc = $('img.front').first().attr('src');
    alert('The source for \'front\' is ' + frontSrc);
    }
}); // end .click handler
```

Use the `hasClass` jQuery function to find out whether or not the element you've clicked on has the 'back' class.  Then use the `img.front` selector to find the image with the front class and retrieve it's source.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am trying to use your method but I can't seem to get it exactly to work. This is what I have:

`$('img.back').click(function(){
    if( last ) {
   if ( $('img.front').first().attr('src') == last.first().attr('src') ) {
     $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
     last.css('visibility', 'hidden');
     found++;
   }
   if (found == 3) {
   window.location.href = "#play2"; 
   }
   last = null;
    } else {
   last = $(this);
    }
  });`

I think it is something with `last = $(this)` or something with when I am trying to hide the pictures with .css()

Comment: Try stepping thru the code with your debugger and see if `last` has the value that you think it should have. If not, ask why

Comment: Just realized that this method only retrieves the frontSource of the same image every time. It will always return the src of flower.gif even when bug.jpg is the front.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('img').click(function(){
    console.log($(this)
           .closest('div[class*=card]') // <-- get closest div with class containing card
           .find('div > a > img') // <-- find all img under that div
           .not(this) // <-- filter out the clicked one
           .attr('src')); // <-- get src of the image not clicked under same div with class containing card
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gweVT/

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your code looks like it should work. I am just a little confused on how exactly to use it in my current code. Should I store the src in a variable so I will be able to compare it?

Comment: Yeah, `var yourVariable = $(this)
           .closest('div[class*=card]').find('div > a > img').not(this).attr('src')` will get you the src of the other `img` tag.  You can store it in a variable so you don't have to use that long line of code to retrieve it each time you need to use it.

Comment: I tried using your method and make an alert() message of the source and it came out to be "undefined."

`$('img').click(function() {
      var frontSrc = $(this).closest('div[class*=card]').find('div > a > img').not(this).attr('src');
      alert(frontSrc);
      });`